# My JS function is not printing anything when two passwords does not matches

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make password field to check each other that the value written by user matches ?

```js
function checkPassword(form) {
  pOne = form.pOne.value;
  pTwo = form.pTwo.value;

  // If password not entered 
  if (pOne == '')
    alert("Please enter Password");

  // If confirm password not entered 
  else if (pTwo == '')
    alert("Please enter confirm password");

  // If Not same return False.     
  else if (pOne != pTwo) {
    // alert ("\nPassword did not match: Please try again...") 
    document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("click", print)

    function print() {
      return document.querySelector(".pass").textContent = "Your password does not match!"
    }

  }

  // If same return True. 
  else {
    document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("click", print)

    function print() {
      return document.querySelector(".pass").textContent = "Your password  match perfectly!"
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<form class="formtwo" onsubmit="checkPassword(this)">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
  <input type="password" name="pOne" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="password" name="pTwo" placeholder="Re-Type Password">
  <p class="pass">djkakj</p>
  <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you binding an event listener instead of just showing the messages?

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, nothing is stopping the form submit from submitting.

Comment: your checkpassword function is called during onsubmit form event, which has been triggered by the click on your submit button. So attaching an event handler to the submit button for an event that has already occured is nonsense.

Comment: and as @Taplar suggested, you have to `return false;` for error cases in `checkpassword` so that submitting is cancelled. update you onsubmit handler with `return checkpassword(this)` so that the cancellation is propagated when returning from onsubmit handler

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check my solution. Hope it's easier to understand. There were some issues in your code.

1. If you want to prevent the form submit if the password doesn't match then you need to use `event.preventDefault` to prevent the default behaviour.
2. You can fire the submit event once and then check for your required values.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.formtwo');
form.addEventListener('submit', checkPassword);

function checkPassword(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let pOne = form.pOne.value;
  let pTwo = form.pTwo.value;

  // If password not entered
  if (pOne == "") alert("Please enter Password");
  // If confirm password not entered
  else if (pTwo == "") alert("Please enter confirm password");
  // If Not same return False.
  else if (pOne != pTwo) {
    document.querySelector(".pass").textContent =
        "Your password does not match!";
  }

  // If same return True.
  else {
    document.querySelector(".pass").textContent =
        "Your password  match perfectly!";
   // submitting form
   form.submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="formtwo">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input type="password" name="pOne" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" name="pTwo" placeholder="Re-Type Password">
    <p class="pass">Password matching status</p>
    <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will never allow a submit

Comment: Yes, the OP is free to handle his submit method to call anywhere :)

Comment: I've added the submit functionality. Thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: Why would you block submit and then sumbit when all you need to do is preventDefault on error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event listener to the form submit before you test

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("formtwo").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    const pOne = this.pOne.value;
    const pTwo = this.pTwo.value;
    const pass = document.querySelector(".pass");
    let errors = [];
    // If password not entered 
    if (pOne == '') errors.push("Please enter Password");
    if (pTwo == '') errors.push("Please enter confirm password");
    if (pOne != pTwo) errors.push("Password did not match: Please try again...")
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault(); // this will stop submission
      alert(errors.join("\n"))
      pass.textContent = "Your password does not match!"
      return;
    }
    pass.textContent = "Your password  match perfectly!"
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="formtwo">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
  <input type="password" name="pOne" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="password" name="pTwo" placeholder="Re-Type Password">
  <p class="pass">djkakj</p>
  <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```